# Use ML Engine dirctly with the data stored on Google BigQuery tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-ml

Is there a way to directly use data on Google BigQuery as train/test data of ML algorithms supported by ML Engine?

What I saw in [documents](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction?hl=en_US&_ga=2.258184714.-1811313932.1498662296) is to use data stored on Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Please refer to [this blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-enable-pandas-to-access-bigquery-from-a-service-account-205a216f0f68) for a detailed guide. The GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/tree/master/blogs/pandas-pvtkey) but here are the key takeaways.

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='trainer',
  version='1.0',
  description='Showing how to use private key',
  url='http://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst',
  author='Google',
  author_email='nobody@google.com',
  license='Apache2',
  packages=['trainer'],
  package_data={'': ['privatekey.json']},
  install_requires=[
      'pandas-gbq==0.4.1',
      'urllib3',
      'google-cloud-bigquery'
  ],
  zip_safe=False)
```

**pkg_query.py**

```
def query_to_dataframe(query):
  import pandas as pd
  import pkgutil
  privatekey = pkgutil.get_data('trainer', 'privatekey.json')
  print(privatekey[:200])
  return pd.read_gbq(query,
                 project_id='cloud-training-demos',
                 dialect='standard',
                 private_key=privatekey)

query = """
SELECT
  year,
  COUNT(1) as num_babies
FROM
  publicdata.samples.natality
WHERE
  year > 2000
GROUP BY
  year
"""

df = query_to_dataframe(query)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: I used the instructions in the blog post and could run python code on my local machine that read data from BigQuery. But as there are hundreds of millions of records in my BigQuery tables, the training phase ended up with a memory low error. Is there a way to use google cloud processors to train the big data on BigQuery?

Comment: the blog post recommends using a VM, did you do that?

Comment: No, I used my local machine. Do you say that I used a GC VM? This has also memory limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I think Torry provided a good answer. To add to that, please take a look into the [Baby weight Example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/tree/master/blogs/sklearn/babyweight). Thus, beside the setup.py file,  you should  modify the model.py as described in [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/blogs/sklearn/babyweight/trainer/model.py).

To make long story short:

```
train_query, eval_query = create_queries()
train_df = query_to_dataframe(train_query)
eval_df = query_to_dataframe(eval_query)
train_x = input_fn(train_df)
```